# How to fix virtualbox's copy and paste problem?

Tags: virtualbox

I am facing issue while trying to copy paste from my Host to Guest or vice versa.
I have tried installing virtual guest but getting below-mentioned error.

[image]

Can you guys help me out with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:***
This is a workaround, not a solution. It works with an Ubuntu host and Ubuntu client. It will not work with specialized network configurations on the VM side.

**Description:**

I've had problems with the clipboard in the past, and for me it's just too much of a bother to fix it. Instead, I have a script that I've put together that allows me to basically create a chat between the host and guest with [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

**Making it happen:**

Using a text editor, create a new plaintext file with the following contents. You can change the port number from 12354 to any open port.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# DESC: vbox-chat allows you to send text back and forth between a VirtualBox 
#     machine an Ubuntu host. This script must be started on the host first and then 
#     on the client.
# ARGS: Pass "host" or "guest" as the first parameter when calling this script

port=12354

id="$1"
id=${id,,}
while [ $(grep -P "^(host|guest)$" <<< "$id" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
do
    clear
    if [ "$id" == "" ]; then
        read -p "Is this the host or guest system (type host or guest): " id
        id=${id,,}
    fi
done

clear
[ "$id" == "host" ] && other="guest" || other="host"
echo -e "Type or paste text into this windo and press enter to have it show up on the\n$other machine\n"
if [ "$id" == "host" ]; then
    nc -l $port
else
    hostIP=$(route -n | grep -P "^0.0.0.0" | tr -s ' ' | cut -f2 -d ' ')
    nc $hostIP $port
fi
```

This script needs to be saved on both host and guest machines (I named it `vm-chat.sh`) and it needs to be executable (`chmod +x /path/to/vm-chat.sh`). Once you've done that:

1. On the host machine, navigate to your script in terminal and run `./vm-chat.sh host` (This *must* be started before the guest instance)
2. On the guest machine, navigate to your script in terminal and run './vm-chat guest' (This *must* be started after the host instance)

Now you can type (or paste) anything you like in the host's terminal window, hit enter, and it will immediately be transferred to the guest's terminal window. Likewise, you can type (or paste) anything you like in the guest's terminal window, hit enter, and it will immediately be transferred to the host's terminal window.

Obviously, this is only going to work for text. If you want to be able to copy and paste files, you could convert them to base64 first, but it's probably not the best way to transfer files.

***WARNING***: All text is transferred over the virtual network between the host and guest in plaintext!